# How to set up tt_address 4.x to work with insert_records in TYPO3 9 LTS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm setting up tt_address for one of our customers. He wants to show single address records with the insert records element. But sadly I didn't have any idea or found a tutorial on how to do that with tt_address 4.3

I have tried to adapt the code from tx_news, but it didn't work out.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
tt_content.shortcut.20.tables := addToList(tt_address)
tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address = USER
tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = TtAddress
    pluginName = ListView
    vendorName = FriendsOfTYPO3

    switchableControllerActions {
        Address {
            1 = show
        }
    }
    settings =< plugin.tt_address.settings
    settings {
        insertRecord = 1
        singleRecords.field = uid
        useStdWrap = singleRecords
    }
}
# For fluid_styled_content
tt_content.shortcut.variables.shortcuts.tables := addToList(tt_address)
tt_content.shortcut.variables.shortcuts.conf.tt_address < tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but why don't you use the native tt_address thing?
You know, you could add a single address in the plugin to be shown?
That should work for listView and singleView oob, and has in fact the same result as what you try.

Comment: For this certain customer this would work, but we have about 50 customers which uses this function in tt_address Versions 1.x, 2.x, 3.x. In the next time all this installations will get an upgrade to Version 4.x. The customers want the function working as it is now.

Fun fact:
tt_address writes it self into the insert records element backend, but give no advise how to set the rendering up.

Comment: Did you try "list" instead of "show" for switchable Controller Action?And IMHO the plugin name is not correct. It's something like tx_ttaddress_listview
or TxTtaddressListview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my TypoScript Configuration:

```
tt_content.shortcut.20.tables := addToList(tt_address)
tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address = USER
tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = TtAddress
    pluginName = ListView
    vendorName = FriendsOfTYPO3
    action = list
    settings =< plugin.tt_address.settings
    settings {
        insertRecord = 1
        singleRecords.field = uid
        useStdWrap = singleRecords
        displayMode = single
    }
}
# For fluid_styled_content
tt_content.shortcut.variables.shortcuts.tables := addToList(tt_address)
tt_content.shortcut.variables.shortcuts.conf.tt_address < tt_content.shortcut.20.conf.tt_address
```

In order that the address get rendered you have to adapt the displayMode_single section of the tt_address template, because the element is not in a array called addresses, but in the propertie contentObjectData.

```
<f:section name="displayMode_single">
<f:if condition="{addresses}">
    <f:then>
        <f:for each="{addresses}" as="address">
            <div class="c-employee__wrapper">
                <f:render partial="Full" arguments="{_all}"/>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:render partial="Full" arguments="{address: contentObjectData}"/>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```